# How to create a repeating n number of coordinates within the range (0,2) where n is much greater than all possible combinations (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, random, coordinates, repeat

I want to generate a random set of coordinates where x and y are within the range (0,2). Repeating one combination is allowed. I tried the following code.

```
possible_coordinates = [(x, y) for x in range(3) for y in range(0,2)]
bomb_coordinates = random.sample(possible_coordinates, k=70)
```

It gives the expected result until the K=6 where k is the required number of coordinate pairs. But when k exceeds 6, it gives an error in random.py.

Please help me out to generate 50 pairs of random coordinates.

```
Traceback               
    <module>    C:\Users\TOSHIBA\Desktop\mypython\to be corrected\run_para.py   12      
    sample  C:\Users\TOSHIBA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\random.py   321     
ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative
```

Comment: @usr2564301 It is a value error. As it indicates, the sample larger than the population or is negative

Comment: @usr2564301 i added the traceback. Please check